# How to use ionic facebook Connect plugin for facebook graph sdk 1.0?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, ionic-framework

I currently am using facebooks javascript sdk on my site using this code snippet:

```
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'appid',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('Logged in');
          } else {
            FB.login();
          }
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

This works great. However, I am converting the app into an Ionic app, so I downloaded the `com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect` plugin, and replaced my initialization script with this:

```
/*
 * @author Ally Ogilvie
 * @copyright Wizcorp Inc. [ Incorporated Wizards ] 2014
 * @file - facebookConnectPlugin.js
 * @about - JavaScript interface for PhoneGap bridge to Facebook Connect SDK
 *
 *
 */

if (!window.cordova) {
// This should override the existing facebookConnectPlugin object created from cordova_plugins.js
    var facebookConnectPlugin = {

        getLoginStatus: function (s, f) {
            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                    s(response);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },

        showDialog: function (options, s, f) {

            if (!options.name) {
                options.name = "";
            }
            if (!options.message) {
                options.message = "";
            }
            if (!options.caption) {
                options.caption = "";
            }
            if (!options.description) {
                options.description = "";
            }
            if (!options.link) {
                options.link = "";
            }
            if (!options.picture) {
                options.picture = "";
            }

            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.ui({
                    method: options.method,
                    message: options.message,
                    name: options.name,
                    caption: options.caption,
                    description: (
                        options.description
                    ),
                    link: options.link,
                    picture: options.picture
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (response && response.request) {
                        s(response);
                    } else {
                        f(response);
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },
        // Attach this to a UI element, this requires user interaction.
        login: function (permissions, s, f) {
            // JS SDK takes an object here but the native SDKs use array.
            var permissionObj = {};
            if (permissions && permissions.length > 0) {
                permissionObj.scope = permissions.toString();
            }

            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    s(response);
                } else {
                    f(response.status);
                }
            }, permissionObj);
        },

        getAccessToken: function (s, f) {
            var response = FB.getAccessToken();
            if (!response) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error("NO_TOKEN");
                } else {
                    f("NO_TOKEN");
                }
            } else {
                s(response);
            }
        },

        logEvent: function (eventName, params, valueToSum, s, f) {
            // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
            s();
        },

        logPurchase: function (value, currency, s, f) {
            // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
            s();
        },

        logout: function (s, f) {
            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.logout( function (response) {
                    s(response);
                })
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },

        api: function (graphPath, permissions, s, f) {
            // JS API does not take additional permissions

            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.api(graphPath, function (response) {
                    if (response.error) {
                        f(response);
                    } else {
                        s(response);
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },

        // Browser wrapper API ONLY
        browserInit: function (appId, version) {
            if (!version) {
                version = "v2.0";
            }
            FB.init({
                appId      : appId,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : version
            })
        }
    };

    // Bake in the JS SDK
    (function () {
        if (!window.FB) {
            console.log("launching FB SDK")
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }
    }());

}
```

However, when I added this, it bumped me up to v2.0 of facebook's sdk.

I even replaced a section of the facebookConnectPlugin.js code with this to enforce the use of api v1.0

```
    // Browser wrapper API ONLY
    browserInit: function (appId, version) {
        if (!version) {
            version = "v1.0";
        }
        FB.init({
            appId      : appId,
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : version
        })
    }
```

However this still gave me version 2.0

Comment: You can only use API v1.0 if your app was created and active before 4/30/2014. If it wasn't you can't use API v1.0

Comment: It was, I've been using API v1.0 successfully. All I'm trying to do is use ionic framework to wrap the site as a mobile app. I think I need to use the plugin because or else it won't launch the facebook app to login - so I can't even login without using the plugin.

Comment: So what is version that is passed into that function?

Comment: `v1.0` is returned when I `console.log(version)` within that function. it still boots me into v2.0 when I uncomment it.

Comment: What is your app id?